# How to filter an UL list using a select-box?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to filter an HTML UL list using a select-box. The code below filters an HTML table using a select-box:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myList");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="myList" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
    <option value="">YEAR</option>
    <option value="y19">2019</option>
    <option value="y18">2018</option>
    <option value="y17">2017</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td><class="y19">Germany</td></tr>
    <tr><td><class="y18">Sweden</td></tr>
    <tr><td><class="y17 y18 y19">UK</td></tr>
    <tr><td><class="y18 y19">Australia</td></tr>
    <tr><td><class="y18">Canada</td></tr>
    <tr><td><class="y18">Italy</td></tr>
</table>
```

I turned the table into an UL but failed to adapt the javascript and make it work. Can anyone help?

```html
<ul id="myUL">
    <li class="y19">Germany</li>
    <li class="y18">Sweden</li>
    <li class="y17 y18 y19">UK</li>
    <li class="y18 y19">Australia</li>
    <li class="y18">Canada</li>
    <li class="y18">Italy</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"...but failed to adapt the javascript and make it work"_ - You've forgotten to post your attempt.

Comment: define "txtValue" somewhere. It's getting an error on that line

Comment: Well did you change the code to look for the list elements and not table rows???? Show your attempt

Comment: @epascarello I actually posted my javascript attempt after the first comment of Andreas. For some reason Krupal Panchal later removed it while editing my post. You can check edit history. This is my second post on this website and I still need to discover its intricacies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="myList" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control'>
<option value="">YEAR</option>
<option value="y19">2019</option>
<option value="y18">2018</option>
<option value="y17">2017</option>
</select>

<ul id="myUL">
<li class="y19">Germany</li>
<li class="y18">Sweden</li>
<li class="y17 y18 y19">UK</li>
<li class="y18 y19">Australia</li>
<li class="y18">Canada</li>
<li class="y18">Italy</li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, i;
input = document.getElementById("myList");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {

    if (li[i].className.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a filtering method, using classes:

```js
// setting up base elements
const select = document.getElementById('myList')
const list = document.getElementById('myUL')
const items = list.querySelectorAll('li')

// filter function
const filter = (val, l, is) => {
  // clear the list
  l.innerHTML = ''
  //iterating over the list
  is.forEach(e => {
    // filter condition
    if (e.classList.contains(val) || val == '') {
      // adding back elements
      l.appendChild(e)
    }
  })
}

// filtering on change event
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  filter(e.target.value, list, items)
})
```

```html
<select id="myList" class='form-control'>
  <option value="">YEAR</option>
  <option value="y19">2019</option>
  <option value="y18">2018</option>
  <option value="y17">2017</option>
</select>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li class="y19">Germany</li>
  <li class="y18">Sweden</li>
  <li class="y17 y18 y19">UK</li>
  <li class="y18 y19">Australia</li>
  <li class="y18">Canada</li>
  <li class="y18">Italy</li>
</ul>
```

The main point is that it's only JavaScript - you don't need anything else.

And then there's an even shorter version:

```js
const select = document.getElementById('myList')
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li')

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  items.forEach(el => {
    if (el.classList.contains(e.target.value) || e.target.value == "") {
      el.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
      el.style.display = 'none'
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<select id="myList" class='form-control'>
  <option value="">YEAR</option>
  <option value="y19">2019</option>
  <option value="y18">2018</option>
  <option value="y17">2017</option>
</select>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li class="y19">Germany</li>
  <li class="y18">Sweden</li>
  <li class="y17 y18 y19">UK</li>
  <li class="y18 y19">Australia</li>
  <li class="y18">Canada</li>
  <li class="y18">Italy</li>
</ul>
```

**The former snippet effectively removes the items from the DOM**, so other won't find them and won't work with them, **the latter only hides the filtered items** and shows the not filtered items.

And for last, here's the jQuery method:

```js
$('#myList').on('change', function(e) {
  const self = this
  $('#myUL li').each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).hasClass(self.value) || self.value == '') {
      $(el).css({
        'display': 'block'
      })
    } else {
      $(el).css({
        'display': 'none'
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myList" class='form-control'>
  <option value="">YEAR</option>
  <option value="y19">2019</option>
  <option value="y18">2018</option>
  <option value="y17">2017</option>
</select>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li class="y19">Germany</li>
  <li class="y18">Sweden</li>
  <li class="y17 y18 y19">UK</li>
  <li class="y18 y19">Australia</li>
  <li class="y18">Canada</li>
  <li class="y18">Italy</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. Both javascript solutions you suggest work perfectly. If I could I would validate both your and AntiqTech solutions.